# ¿Existe una palabra en español para designar a un agorero exagerado?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Una duda que nos acaba de surgir. En español tenemos:

> **[agorero, ra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=16miGim)**
>
> De *agüero* y *-ero*.
>
> 1. adj. Que predice males o desdichas. Dicho especialmente de la persona pesimista. U. t. c. s.

Y por otro lado:

> **[exagerar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HAZ24tq)**
>
> Del lat. *exaggerāre*.
>
> 1. tr. Encarecer, dar proporciones excesivas.
> 2. tr. Decir, representar o hacer algo traspasando los límites de lo verdadero, natural, ordinario, justo o conveniente.

Estamos buscando una palabra que aúne los dos términos: una persona que predice males, pero dando para ello motivos demasiado exagerados.

¿Existe un término así en español?

Comment: _Exajorero_ ¡! (la _j_ para mantener el sonido)

Comment: @fedorqui se confundiría con _hexagorero_: seis veces agorero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Un [catastrofista](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7vOl5ah) es alguien que "tiene o demuestra [catastrofismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7vN6RHn)"

> catastrofismo
>
> Actitud de quien, **exagerando** con fines generalmente intimidatorios, **denuncia o pronostica gravísimos males**.

Comment: ¡Esa era la palabra que estaba buscando! ¡Gracias! Lamento no haber sabido explicarla mejor.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo No pasa nada hombre! No decimos en _meta_ que qué lástima que pocas de nuestras preguntas dan para varias respuestas? Pues mira, esta da par muchas aportaciones!! ;-D

Answer (score 1):

Parece ser que el en español más que **exagerado**  tendemos a calificar como **mal augur** en lugar de **augur exagerado**

Para **mal augur** si existen términos como:

**aguafiestas**, **gafe** o **mal agüero** (ave de mal agüero)

Answer (score 1):

Para la descripción que haces, acá en México es común usar el término **"fatalista"**.

Comment: ¡No está mal! Sin embargo, según el diccionario "fatalista" hace más hincapié en la resignación de la persona más que en ser exagerado. ¿Se usa en México con ese sentido de exageración?

Comment: A mi parecer, y considerando mi región, sí tiene esa tendencia - es un poco de exageración con tendencia a un resultado negativo.

Answer (score 0):

Para mi sería `derrotista` que es aquella persona que tiene una actitud de [derrotismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CJcKR2A)

> derrotismo
>
> 2. m. Actitud de desaliento o pesimismo en cualquier empeño.

Si alguien, en cualquier desepeño, está *augurando* un mal resultado, está siendo exagerado ya que no todas las situaciones acabarán mal.

También se podría decir de esta persona que es un [agonías](http://dle.rae.es/?id=16QIHsj).

En cualquier caso, la parte de `exagerado` es un poco subjetiva. Un *agorero exagerado* **siempre** piensa que va a ocurrir lo peor? O no, siempre, pero cuando lo hace **sobreestima** de de manera muy fatalista las consecuencias de lo que puede ocurrir?

Comment: Un derrotista es para mí sinónimo de pesimista, que espera lo peor siempre. Lo de exagerado es más bien referido a las razones que se esgrimen para serlo. Los habrá que tengan motivos razonables, y los habrá totalmente exagerados. Estos seguro que reciben un nombre concreto.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Entonces no es "exagerado" (irrazonable tal vez?) pero la parte de _exagerado_ sigue necesitando matiz. Además, tendría algo que ver que pese a lo "irrazonable" de su predicción pesimista esta se cumpliese (o no)? Es decir, buscamos "irrazonable y fallido portavoz de la fatalidad"? Si vamos a ser muy especifícos quizá convendría editar la pregunta, pero sigo pensando que _pesimista, derrotista y agonías_ entran en la categoría de "exagera las posibilidades de que algo malo ocurra o exagera las consecuencias de algo" y que por definición ven el vaso siempre medio vacío.