# Cómo traducir "fearmonger" / "fearmongerism"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

> [Fearmonger](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fearmonger)
>
> Someone who spreads fear, or needlessly raises the alarm.
>
> [Fearmongering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fearmongering) (or scaremongering)
>
> The spreading of frightening and exaggerated rumors of an impending danger or the habit or tactic of purposely and needlessly arousing public fear about an issue

Un *fearmonger* es una persona que saca aprovecho de difundir miedo y pánico. Suele hacerse mediante la manipulación, la exageración y la repetición de información y otras tácticas psicológicas basadas en el miedo. Al meter miedo a la población que es objetivo de esta campaña se les influencia para que actúen dejándose llevar por este miedo. Básicamente, a través del miedo (y la manipulación) establezco una necesidad (de mis servicios).

Por ejemplo:

- Supongamos que soy una megaempresa farmacéutica, y se dan una serie de casos de gripe aviar, porcina o lo que sea. Mediante la manipulación (*fearmongerism*) puedo manipular a la población (o la opinión pública) para que se asuste y piense que la cosa es mucho más grave y frecuente de lo que en realidad es. Como resultado la gente pide que se produzcan más vacunas y yo me lleno los bolsillos a base de venderlas.
- El uso es frecuente en política: Que si hay unos colectivos que tal y cual (nos quitan nuestros derechos/dinero/mujeres/costumbres), que si ese otro país tiene armas nucleares, que si la oposición va a hacer una locura que nos va a llevar a la ruina de nuestros mercados financieros.

A mi lo mejor que se me ocurre es "tratante del miedo". En cualquier caso, también tenemos "fishmonger", que sería un pescadero o tratante de pescado, y "warmonger" que sería un "instigador de la guerra" (alguien que por ejemplo hace que dos potencias terminen enfrentadas para sacar tajada del conflicto a base de vender armas, servicios militares, etc.)

Hay alguna traducción mejor en español para "Fearmonger/fearmongerism"?

Comment: Se me ocurre *alarmista* pero le falta ese matiz de instigador o que se beneficie con ello.

Comment: En el caso de la política es común oír la expresión "la política del miedo".

Comment: Relacionada (y respondida por ti): [¿Existe una palabra en español para designar a un agorero exagerado?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19492/12637).

Comment: ¿Será un *siembramiedo*?

Answer (score 4):

Creo que *fearmongerism* se traduce en español como "**política del miedo**". Por supuesto, se usa en política justo con el significado que comentas, pero también se puede extender a otro tipo de "políticas", como la "política de empresa". Así que se podría usar también en el caso de empresas farmacéuticas y otras. Lo malo es que así, *fearmonger* se traduciría como "que usa/practica la política del miedo", no se me ocurre nada más corto.

En todo caso, los ejemplos que he visto hacen referencia casi todos a la política más que a empresas:

> *Coherente con la política del miedo que, según los demócratas, el presidente George W. Bush ha venido instrumentando desde que tuvieron lugar los atentados del 11 de setiembre, el vicepresidente Dick Cheney advirtió a los electores norteamericanos que si se equivocan el día de las elecciones presidenciales existe el peligro de que haya nuevos atentados.*
>
> Diario El Clarín, 09/09/2004 (Argentina).
>
> ---
>
> *Pero la política del miedo no se utiliza únicamente para conseguir el apoyo de la población en cuanto a las guerras y conflictos, sino que también sirve para convencer a la gente de que determinadas decisiones políticas o económicas son necesarias.*
>
> Juan Pérez Ventura, "[Cómo funciona el mundo (1): la política del miedo](http://papeldeperiodico.com/2013/10/como-funciona-el-mundo-1-la-politica-del-miedo/)", 2013 (España).

Answer (score 3):

Ofrezco algunas opciones más:

**alarmismo, alarmista**

**siembra de miedo, sembrador de miedo**

Supongo que los ejemplos de uso y las definiciones no se necesitan.  En caso de que sí, avísame, por favor.